# Python Banner Grabber

Tags: python, sockets, hexdump

I'm trying to make a banner grabber that prompts a user for their ip address and port. What I have so far is:

(Here's a pic of the bannergrabber code if the site shows it weird
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqpJf.jpg
and a pic of the hexdump code
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q56gI.jpg)

```
import socket
import sys

def bannergrabber(ip_address,port):
  try:
    s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((ip_address,port))
    banner = s.recv(4096)
    print ip_address + ":" + banner
  except
    return
```

Pretty obvious I'm not sure what I'm doing. I want to establish a TCP connection with the IP and port which is why I have `socket.SOCK_STREAM` in there. After that I'm printing the output with this `hexdump` function:

```
def myhexdump(src, length=16)
  result=[]
  for i in range(0, len(src), length):
    substring = src[i:i+length]
    result.append("%04x" %i)
    hex = "".join("%X" % ord(c) for c in substring)
    result.append("%-*s %s\n" %(length*3, hex, substring))
  print b".join(result)
```

Comment: "[T]he site shows it weird" if you don't use the code-block ; )

Comment: There's something wrong with this line: `hex = ".join("%X" % ord© for c in substring)`; I suspect you meant `"".join(...)`. And you've misspelt `ipaddresss` in the list of arguments for `bannergrabber()`, which means it will throw an error when you try to access `ipaddress`.

Comment: The `".join(...)` seems pretty strange. What is `©` doing there?

Comment: Moreover, you forgot a `:` after `except` in `bannergrabber`

Comment: Yea, there's a unicode character, probably a typo…

Comment: @septi, to my mind, it's difficult to make such a typo using standard QWERTY keyboard

Comment: Who knows what system/keyboard he uses… ; )

Comment: It's (c), I changed it up there.

Comment: Shall we correct `".join(...)` here?

Comment: @ForceBru on Mac it's Alt+G

Comment: @septi, yes, I know, but in that case the OP did it on purpose, I think

Comment: What's `print b".join(result)`?? Maybe it's `"".join(...)` again?